# How to list all storage paths in android?

Tags: android, storage

I want to get list of paths of all available storage drives for example internal memory,  Memory card, usb otg drive etc..
At least give suggestions to get path of removable storage.

Comment: For the most part, all that is done from the [`Environment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class. There's not one method to list all directories

Comment: Moreover, [you do not have arbitrary access to most of that ("Memory card, usb otg drive") through the filesystem on Android 4.4+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: See this answer by Ardock for an in-depth analysis. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40201333/940834

Comment: If you are on Android 7 and above the `StorageManager` will gladly tell you which `StorageVolumes` are available.

Comment: For Android 5, 6 and 7 you can also look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Comment: What is the string argument for    getExternalFilesDirs (String s)

Comment: Make it `null`. As you can see with a simple Google.