# Failed to delete files on removable storage

Tags: java, android

I was trying to delete files from local storage on the Android Lollipop by the following line:

```
new File(path).delete();
```

Deleting file that resides in Internal storage works fine. But failed to do so on file that is located on external removable storage. I've checked that the file do exists but cannot be overwritten. Moreover, permission has already been granted to the app.

> In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** or **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** system permissions.

As stated in the documentation, no luck though.

Googled for available solutions, but doesn't satisfy the problem.

Comment: show the path ur using

Comment: The path was "/storage/19F6-2B13/fdasfdas". That points to a file.

Comment: Before you delete the file, can you check `file.exists()` and see whether the file really exists ?

Comment: As mentioned, I've performed checks on the file. The method returned to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not delete file on removable media starting from KitKat (API 19). You have to interact with user by means [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), get access object for the file you are going to delete - [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) - and call `delete` operation on it. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068984/universal-way-to-write-to-external-sd-card-on-android/40201333#40201333) for deep understanding of this nightmare.

Comment: That helped. There's no nightmare on older API

Comment: Yes, everytime google release new version of Android, they make new nightmare for developers 