# is Unlocking external SD Card writing for all apps in Android 7 possible on my Rooted LG Stylo 3 plus

Tags: android, lg

**UPDATE I made the code changes and restarted. The SDfix now says its already been fixed and nothing else is needed. But I'm still not allowed to write to my SDcard? Now my original question is no longer relevant.

[Here's a link to a pic of the original post if you want to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2zt8.png)

What was once a simple question has turn into something that is above my understanding.

All I want is to use my SDcard.

I've read this post  [Universal way to write to external SD card on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068984/universal-way-to-write-to-external-sd-card-on-android?rq=1)

Do i have to find and edit each and every manifesto on my LG Stylo 3 Plus if so what exactly do i add to it? Is there any other way?

Comment: Well now that you are so close whats preventing you to do so?

Comment: I'm a noob and fear that if it's wrong my phone not work
the xml had warnings about being very careful